Why I am unable to locate proceed button on robot framework
Why I am unable to locate proceed button on robotframework seleniumlibrary.
I have tried below XPath expressions:
//input[@id="btnProceed"]

and
//input[contains(text(),"btnProceed")]

locater from chrome browser.
<input type="submit" name="btnProceed" value="Proceed" id="btnProceed" title="Click to Proceed" class="btn">


What does your HTML code look like?

The first XPath expression looks OK, second is incorrect. Having said that, there could be various reasons why selenium is not able to locate the element. Share the URL of the website if it's public? If not share more of HTML around the targeted element.

I'm curious what is the error you're getting for the first xpath.  I agree, that looks like it should work.

As others have said I would need to see more of the HTML to work out why the first example isn't working. Are there multiple elements using the btnProceed id on the page? If the element is held within a modal it could also throw things off.
For the second example to work the text within the <input> element would have to be 'btnProceed'. Something like this:

<input type="submit" name="btnProceed" value="Proceed" id="btnProceed" title="Click to Proceed" class="btn">btnProceed</input>



Try to right click on the element and copy the jspath and then use the variables as:
right click->inspect->copy->jspath
dom = 
Example:
${profile_element}        
    ...    dom=document.querySelector('xweb-shellbar').shadowRoot
    ...    .querySelector('div[id="shellbarContainer"] > ui5-shellbar-sf-header').shadowRoot
    ...    .querySelector('header > div:nth-child(3) > div > ui5-button-sf-header[data-ui5-stable="profile"]').shadowRoot
    ...    .querySelector('button')

Click Element    ${profile_element}

This way you could dynamically select the right element every single time.

I think it could happen because of some reasons:

The button might not be interactable because:


it is in an iframe. If it is in an iframe, switch to the iframe first.

Select Frame    iframe_name_or_id

It is hidden by CSS or JavaScriptIt or it has not loaded yet. Wait for the element to become visible.

Wait Until Element Is Visible   //input[@id="btnProceed"]
or
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //input[@id="btnProceed"]

If the button is off-screen or scrolled out of view, selenium may not locate it. Use Scroll Element Into View.

Scroll Element Into View       //input[@id="btnProceed"]

You can capture the screen to verify whether the button is visible.

